# Cannot use namespace 'Boom' as a type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, hapi.js

I am using `hapi` for one of my node+typescript project. I am trying to update `hapi` to the new `@hapi/hapi` package, due to the deprecation of the "naked" packages. I've changed `@types/hapi` to `@types/hapi__hapi`.

As soon as I updated, I started getting the TypeScript error -

```
node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:514:32 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Boom' as a type.

514     response: ResponseObject | Boom;
                                   ~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:4050:18 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Boom' as a type.

4050         (Error | Boom) |
                      ~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

Here's the dependencies I have in package.json -

```
{
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/hapi__boom": "7.4.1",
    "@types/hapi__hapi": "18.2.5",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "16.0.1",
    "@types/nock": "10.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.4.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "nock": "11.4.0",
    "nodemon": "1.19.4",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "typescript": "3.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@hapi/boom": "8.0.1",
    "@hapi/hapi": "18.4.0",
    "@hapi/joi": "16.1.7",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "axios-retry": "3.1.2"
  },
...
}
```

I checked the `node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts` file and it was importing `Boom` using the following way -

```
import * as Boom from '@hapi/boom';
```

When I change it to

```
import { Boom } from '@hapi/boom';
```

and it solved the error.

I can't change the `index.d.ts` file, as it's from `@types/hapi__hapi` package, but I want to solve this issue. Is there anything I can do to not have this error, such as downgrading to some specific version?

Comment: Sounds like you need to report a bug

Comment: @Liam thanks, I was going to post the bug, but found out they already have a workaround which was to downgrade the @hapi/boom package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked the issues at [`@hapi/boom`](https://github.com/hapijs/boom/issues) and they included types in 7.x release which were breaking typescript build. They [removed types from 7.x releases](https://github.com/hapijs/boom/issues/248), but [put them back in 8.x](https://github.com/hapijs/boom/issues/251), and since I was using `@hapi/boom 8.0.1`, it was conflicting with the existing types.

All the hapi ecosystem is going to include type definitions in them, but other packages are not updated to do it (as far as I could tell), thus the only way to resolve this issue without breaking breaking TypeScript builds is to downgrade `@hapi/boom` to `7.4.11`.

PS: I found out the github issues minutes after posting the question, but I am still open for better answers, if there is one.

Comment: You can also do a post-install delete of one of the definition files. I think that this is a poor idea but might work in some situations.